# Change date (but not time) in datetime column to date in date column

Tags: numbers

I have a table with, among others, two columns, one for a date (e.g. "22. March 2021"), the other for a time (e.g. "16:00"). Internally, the date column contains only dates, but the time column internally contains date and time (e.g. "16:00" is actually 22.03.2021 16:00:00 with only the time shown, as the footer makes clear). This is a problem, when I want to sort the table and the date-part of the time column doesn't coincide with the date in the date column (which often happens when I copy-paste a time from another field).

What I would like to do is to either

1. strip the date from the internal representation of the time column (but I believe times without dates aren't possible in numbers)

or

2. replace the date in the internal representation of the time column by the date from the date column.

Can either of the two be achieved without manually editing each and every cell?

---

*Example for option 2.*

[image]

should become:

[image]

Note the footer!

Comment: Can't you just use a formula which takes the date from the left column and the time from the right, and creates a new datetime value?

Comment: @nohillside I guess, except not "just".

Comment: @fluctuatingpsychosis what am I missing `=DATEVALUE(datecol)+TIMEVALUE(timecol)`.  You probably also need to format to show "DATE + TIME" .. but other than that ??

Comment: @MrR Thank you. I tried that. Now I have a third column but haven't actually changed the existing second column. And when I try to delete the second (time) column and replace it with the new third, the value in the new third column is lost because the reference column no longer exists. So calculating a new column doesn't actually achieve my goal of changing the *value* within an existing column. I have tried to copy-paste the results from the third column to the second column or pasting them to a code editor first to reformat the dates and enclose them in quotes, but they turned into strings.

Comment: This is what hidden columns are for.  If you were to copy the data in again then it wouldn't calculate.  You can hide the columns you don't want.  If you want to replace the value copy the elements in the combined, then go back to the one you want to replace and go "Paste Formula Results"

Comment: @MrR The problem with that is that I have to continually edit the table, entering new rows manually. If I have to always unhide the hidden column for that, then that's a lot of hassle. I'm hoping to clean up the existing entries.